# Restsharp - how to serialize a list of enums to strings

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

I have an `List<AnimalsEnum> Foo` property in a class that I'm serializing to XML with RestSharp for the body of a request. I'd like the output to be:

```
<rootNode>
    ... existing content...
    <Foo>Elephant</Foo>
    <Foo>Tiger</Foo>
    .... more content
```

Instead, for the relevant serialisation part, I have

```
<Foo>
    <AnimalsEnum />
    <AnimalsEnum />
</Foo>
```

I'd like to convert the enum values to strings and remove the container element that is automatically added. Is this possible with RestSharp? I thought it may be possible with attributes, but apparently not. Am I going to have to wrangle this output myself with a custom serialiser?

Code is difficult to post, but keeping with the example:

```
class Bar
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public List<AnimalsEnum> Foo{get;set;}
    public enum AnimalsEnum {Tiger,Elephant,Monkey}
}
```

and to serialize into a request

```
var req = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);
req.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Xml;
req.AddQueryParameter("REST-PAYLOAD", "");
req.AddXmlBody(myBar);
```

Comment: Could you post relevant code?

Comment: @Dennis updated question

Comment: Why do you want output to be `<Foo>Elephant</Foo>` and so on? I've looked into BCL's `XmlSerializer`, it serializes enums from list as `<AnimalsEnum>Tiger</AnimalsEnum>`, and this looks much more correct instead of repetition of `Foo` tags.

Comment: Don't blame me, blame ebay! It's ultimately for the ebay api

Comment: I'm afraid, we have two problems here. First one is the bug in default `RestRequest`'s serializer. Second one is that server wants request to be serialized in some non-standard way. IMHO, both could be resolved by replacement of default serializer - you need to implement `ISerializer` on top of `XmlSerializer` from BCL, and write custom serialization logic. Then assign your serializer to `RestRequest.XmlSerializer`.

Comment: I've traced through the serialisation code for RestSharp and it's buggy as hell! I've already had to modify the deserialisation code to make it work with lists correctly! I can't understand why this library has so many users!

Comment: Try following : string[] animals = Enum.GetValues(typeof(AnimalsEnum)).Cast<AnimalsEnum>().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();

Comment: it's surprising how easier things became once I dropped RestSharp and made a basic class around `HttpClient`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in [`DotNetXmlSerializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/DotNetXmlSerializer.cs) of RestSharp to make Microsoft's [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) do the actual serialization.  Then you can use [XML serialization attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z.aspx#Anchor_2) to specify that the `List<AnimalsEnum>` of `Bar` should be serialized without an outer container element by applying [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx):

```
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public List<AnimalsEnum> Foo { get; set; }
    public enum AnimalsEnum { Tiger, Elephant, Monkey }
}
```

Then, when making the request, do:

```
var req = new RestSharp.RestRequest(RestSharp.Method.POST);

// Use XmlSerializer to serialize Bar
req.XmlSerializer = new RestSharp.Serializers.DotNetXmlSerializer(); 

req.RequestFormat = RestSharp.DataFormat.Xml;
req.AddQueryParameter("REST-PAYLOAD", "");
req.AddXmlBody(myBar);
```

Note that `Bar` must be public because `XmlSerializer` can only serialize public types.