# Custom serializing nested collection objects

Tags: c#, restsharp, xmlserializer

I am trying to serialize a C# object with RestSharp's XmlSerializer.

My model is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

Client code is like this, nothing fancy here.

```
        List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();
        addresses.Add(new Address { City = "NY" });
        addresses.Add(new Address { City = "Istanbul" });

        Person person = new Person { Name = "Mike", Addresses = addresses };

        Console.WriteLine(new RestSharp.Serializers.XmlSerializer().Serialize(person));
```

The output is, as expected, like this:

```
<Person>
  <Name>Mike</Name>
  <Addresses>
    <Address>
      <City>NY</City>
    </Address>
    <Address>
      <City>Istanbul</City>
    </Address>
  </Addresses>
</Person>
```

Is there a way to get the following result? ("Addresses" element names are removed)

```
   <Person>
      <Name>Mike</Name>
        <Address>
          <City>NY</City>
        </Address>
        <Address>
          <City>Istanbul</City>
        </Address>
    </Person>
```

Comment: Add XmlElement : [XmlElement("Address")]public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

Comment: I think that works with System.Xml.Serialization namespace. RestSharp ignores that attribute.

Comment: try to add [Serializable] attribute to your classes.

Comment: Use the built-in [`DotNetXmlSerializer`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp/Serializers/DotNetXmlSerializer.cs) then apply `[XmlElement("Address")]` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42165873/3744182).  In fact, is that a duplicate?

Comment: Well I could not come up with the idea of using DotNetXmlSerializer. Thanks fot mentioning that. I think RestSharp's native xml serializer does not support some of the attributes.